# How is a C# class with no implementation valid?

Tags: c#, .net, class

I've stumbed across this class in an existing code base:

```
[Serializable]
public class PillowFight
{
    public PillowFight(object providedObject);

    public object providedObject { get; }
    public Dictionary<string, PillowData> Properties { get; }

    public PillowData GetPillowByName(string pillowName);
    public void SetPillowValue(string pillowName, object value);
}
```

I would not have expected this to compile because of the missing implementations on the constructor, GetPillowByName and SetPillowValue since it's not abstract or an interface.  This is valid?  Why would one do this and what's the advantage?

Comment: `This is valid?` What is hard in testing it?

Comment: What makes you think it *does* compile? Have you tried compiling it? That doesn't look like it would compile to me...

Comment: Are you sure you're not looking at the metadata definition? It's not partial methods/classes either. Shouldn't compile.

Comment: This is no valid c# code. Does that compiles? Presumably you're looking at metadata in VisualStudio.

Comment: @knittl: You've missed the point - there's a constructor being specified, but without a body.

Comment: It shouldn't be valid. Seems to me a decompiled code in Visual Studio, e.g., when you press F12 on a class definition, where its source is not available, and it gets decompiled.

Comment: @JonSkeet: yep, just noticed …

Comment: when I tried, it gives me compilation error : Error 1 'PillowFight.PillowFight(object)' must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial E:\My Projects\StackOverflow\StackOverflow.Windows\PillowFight.cs 11 16 StackOverflow.Windows

Comment: All 5 methods will cause a compilation error here.

Comment: Ha, totally missed the [from metadata] in the tab!!! My bad.  Of course I compiled with no problem which is what shocked me.

Comment: On that note, you can use some kind of decompiler program such as Reflector to see the code behind it

Comment: @L.B - Nothing except for the fact that I was looking at it in Visual Studio and compiling with no problem.  The file I was looking at was in a project that was part of the solution, so I have no idea why it was showing me the metadata when I went to definition.  That is what was confusing.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, it is not valid. Probably you have seen this when using the 'go to definition (F12)' function in Visual Studio. If the source is in another assembly, it will only show the outline, not the actual code.

See the corresponding [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/paYfeC) (which doesn't compile).

Error:

> PillowFight.PillowFight(object)' must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial

Comment: You can usually tell if this is the case by the label of the tab you're working with - VS will append "[from metadata]" and Xamarin will say "Assembly Browser"

Comment: Nailed it.  Could NOT figure out what was happening.  My entire world shifted and I thought I had missed some rediculous feature release.